# JTable checkbox (Boolean) column non editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I made a JTable and implemented custom table model for it to render checkbox for boolean values. Problem I am having is that checkboxes are not editable.

```
public class JTableBooleanAsCheckbox extends JPanel {
public JTableBooleanAsCheckbox() {
    initializeUI();
}

private void initializeUI() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 150));

    JTable table = new JTable(new BooleanTableModel());
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void showFrame() {
    JPanel panel = new JTableBooleanAsCheckbox();
    panel.setOpaque(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Boolean as Checkbox");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JTableBooleanAsCheckbox.showFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

Table Model is as below.

```
class BooleanTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    String[] columns = {"STUDENT ID", "NAME", "SCORE", "PASSED"};
    Object[][] data = {
            {"S001", "ALICE", 90.00, Boolean.TRUE},
            {"S002", "BOB", 45.50, Boolean.FALSE},
            {"S003", "CAROL", 60.00, Boolean.FALSE},
            {"S004", "MALLORY", 75.80, Boolean.TRUE}
    };

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columns[column];
    }

    //
    // This method is used by the JTable to define the default
    // renderer or editor for each cell. For example if you have
    // a boolean data it will be rendered as a check box. A
    // number value is right aligned.
    //
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return data[0][columnIndex].getClass();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex,int columnIndex) {
        if(rowIndex == 3)
           return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? I set the cell editable for the cells containing the checkboxes. Still unable to change the status (check of uncheck) of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the `isCellEditable` method of your `BooleanTableModel`.
Instead of `rowIndex == 3` you need to check for `columnIndex == 3`.
It should be:

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if(columnIndex == 3)
       return true;
    return false;
}
```

Furthermore you need to override its `setValueAt` method,
because the [`setValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#setValueAt-java.lang.Object-int-int-) method of `AbstractTableModel` does nothing:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    data[rowIndex][columnIndex] = aValue;
}
```